# PHP Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (array and object issues)

Tags: php, arrays, object

I was trying to copy this code:

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $id          = $product['id'];
    $name        = $product['name'];
    $description = $product['description'];
    $price       = $product['price'];
?>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $product['picture']; ?>" /></td>
        <td><b><?php echo $name; ?></b><br />
        <?php echo $description; ?><br />
          Price:<big style="color:green">
          $<?php echo $price; ?></big><br /><br />
<?php
    echo form_open('cart/add');
    echo form_hidden('id', $id);
    echo form_hidden('name', $name);
    echo form_hidden('price', $price);
    echo form_submit('action', 'Add to Cart');
    echo form_close();
?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

and here is my code:

```
<?php
   foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
      $id      = $blog['id'];
      $title   = $blog['title'];
      $content = $blog['content'];
?>
      <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
      <h1> <?php echo $content; ?> </h1>

<?php
}
?>
```

I get this error every time I run my code: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: Try object syntax instead: `$blog->id`

Comment: well $blog seems to be an object. Just print_r() your $blogs to review it's structure

Comment: try to use -> operator

Comment: Stupidly marked as duplicate. The linked "duplicate" question is about using `json_decode` to return an array (instead of it's default object).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The example you copied from is using data in the form of an array holding arrays, you are using data in the form of an array holding objects. Objects and arrays are not the same, and because of this they use different syntaxes for accessing data.

If you don't know the variable names, just do a `var_dump($blog);` within the loop to see them.

**The simplest method - access $blog as an object directly:**

Try (assuming those variables are correct):

```
<?php 
    foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        $id         = $blog->id;
        $title      = $blog->title;
        $content    = $blog->content;
?>

<h1> <?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<h1> <?php echo $content; ?> </h1>

<?php } ?>
```

**The alternative method - access $blog as an array:**

Alternatively, you may be able to turn `$blog` into an array with `get_object_vars` ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)):

```
<?php
    foreach($blogs as &$blog) {
        $blog     = get_object_vars($blog);
        $id       = $blog['id'];
        $title    = $blog['title'];
        $content  = $blog['content'];
?>

<h1> <?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<h1> <?php echo $content; ?> </h1>

<?php } ?>
```

It's worth mentioning that this isn't necessarily going to work with nested objects so its viability entirely depends on the structure of your `$blog` object.

**Better than either of the above - Inline PHP Syntax**

Having said all that, if you want to use PHP in the most readable way, neither of the above are right. When using PHP intermixed with HTML, it's considered best practice by many to use PHP's [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), this would reduce your whole code from nine to four lines:

```
<?php foreach($blogs as $blog): ?>
    <h1><?php echo $blog->title; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $blog->content; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Yet, the php manuals say you can use the array notation for objects. So, why do we háve to use "->"?

Comment: @e-motiv  Yes, I'm facing the same issue currently: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Answer (score 36):

$blog is an object not an array

try using `$blog->id` instead of `$blog['id']`

Answer (score 4):

$blog is an object, not an array, so you should access it like so:

```
$blog->id;
$blog->title;
$blog->content;
```

Answer (score 4):

There might two issues

```
1) $blogs may be a stdObject
```

or

```
2) The properties of the array might be the stdObject
```

Try using var_dump($blogs)  and see the actual problem if the properties of array have stdObject try like this

```
$blog->id;
$blog->content;
$blog->title;
```

Comment: A quick var_dump() of each might be in order.

Answer (score 4):

If you're iterating over an object instead of an array, you'll need to access the properties using:

```
$id = $blog->id;
$title = $blog->title;
$content = $blog->content;
```

That, or change your object to an array.

Comment: i want my code to look just like from where i copy the code. why do i have to change it like that? isnt the code from where i am copying is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

StdClass object is accessed by using `->`

```
foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
    $id         = $blog->id;
    $title  = $blog->title;
    $content    = $blog->content;
}
```

Comment: yes... but i was wondering why cant i copy the code above. like this  foreach ($blogs as $blog) {

   $id   = $blog['id'];
   $title   = $blog['title'];
   $content  = $blog['content'];
 ?>
   
   <h1> <?php echo $title; ?></h1>
   <h1> <?php echo $content; ?> </h1>

Comment: @EmmanuelJosephUBastero - You can't copy the code because they're working with an array of arrays, and you're working with an array of objects. It's like asking why you can't copy how someone drives a car on a unicycle, they are totally different tools. I explained in my answer how to turn your objects into arrays.