# json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: arrays, json, twitter, decode

I have the following code, in which I am getting Tweets in JSON format on an HTML page, I want this to be displayed neatly on an HTML page. I have included the foreach loop, however I am getting the following error: " json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ".

```
function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) 
{
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

$resArr = json_decode($tweets, 1); // decodes the json string to an array

if (is_array($resArr))
{
    foreach ($resArr as $tweet)
    {
        echo $tweet['text']."<br />";
    }
}
```

I have also tried using the following code, after reading other suggestions, however an error "Using $this when not in object context":

```
$resArr = json_decode($this->item->extra_fields, true);
```

Would anyone please provide me with some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have switched from using arrays to using objects I had to alter the PHP code as follows.

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet)
{
    echo $tweet->text;
    echo "<br />\n";
}
```

This answer explains it best, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589380/2675041

Answer (score 1):

Your error "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" hints that $tweets is already an array (not a string). Try the following:

```
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

foreach ($tweets as $tweet)
{
    echo $tweet->text."<br />";
}
```

Comment: I had tried that, however I got the following error: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: Edited: Use -> instead of []