# Array and object issue in symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I'm sending an object via my Action in Symfony, but I cannot retrieve it in my view.

This is the Action code:

```
public function testphpAction()
    {
/*SOME DOCTRINE CODE*/
$productos = $consulta->getResult();
return $this->render('TPMainBundle:Default:test.html.php', array(
                'productos' => $productos,
    ));
}
```

I tried the solutions from this thread but with no effort: [PHP Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (array and object issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589313/php-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-array-and-object-issues)

This is the code of my view 'test.html.php':

```
foreach($productos as $producto) {
    echo $producto['descripcion'];
}
// This displays the error: "Cannot use object of type TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works as array
```

So I tried the solution from the other thread:

```
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
        $id         = $producto->id;
        echo $id;
//But it throws the error: Cannot access private property TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works::$id
```

Neither this worked:

```
$id = $productos->id;
// Throw: "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

How can I access it? I don't have this problem if I render to a twig template, but I need to use php.

The var_dump of $productos is this: (I ommited the other objects in this chain)

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works)#290 (4) { ["id":"TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works":private]=> int(1) ["descripcion":"TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works":private]=> string(30) "Landing page for a toys store." ["img":"TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works":private]=> string(12) "images/1.jpg" ["preview":"TP\MainBundle\Entity\Works":private]=> string(13) "images/1m.jpg" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your getters, and then use them.

for example in this

```
foreach ($productos as $producto) 
{ $id = $producto->id; echo $id; }
```

Try

```
$producto->getId();
```

instead of

```
 $producto->id;
```

assuming you defined your getter.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I tried something like public function{ etc thinking about the getter.......  but producto->getId() worked inside the foreach !! Thank you

Comment: depending on what you want, that's easy and depends on your logic; for example you can use <\br> html tag in the foreach loop.

Comment: The modification doesn't work when the doctrine query is different....  I changed it in order to select with a WHERE clause,  (SELECT p FROM TPMainBundle:Works p WHERE p.id = :id)  and now I'm getting "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"   do you know why?

Comment: actually, this have nothing to do with my answer, foreach expects an iterable list, but your query returns a single result, so not iterable. Other thing, don't accept and then deny it depending on your modification, that's not how the site works.

Comment: Not about accept or not, you are asking for answers to two unrelated question. Anyway I hope I helped you and your where query works.

Comment: Yes! you helped me a lot, but i'm still having problems with the other unrelated issue, so I'll open another thread.

Comment: just get rid of the foreach loop. you have only one single result to display

Comment: I tried that, but look at this:  Now my view have NO for each loop!!  My view can be anything, but it will keep saying "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 0):

```
$id         = $producto->id;
```

This won't work because whether the property is not publicly accessible or the Object does not have that property.

The `Work` object has `description`, but it's private, so you'd have to create a getter function to echo it.

e.g

`echo $producto->getDescription();`